# jQuery Mobile Split Button List Question

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to get an image on the right hand side but it always appear as an arrow.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g">


<li>
<a href="#">
 <img src="../Images/play_button.gif" width="16" height="16" class="ui-li-icon" />
<span>Item 1</span>
<span class="ui-li-count">12</span>
</a>

<a href="#">
       // I want an image to appear here
</a>

</li>

<li>
<img src="../Images/play_button.gif" width="16" height="16" class="ui-li-icon" />
<span>Item 2</span>
<span class="ui-li-count">9</span>
</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what is wrong with the layout you're using for the list view, 
I would study the documentation and compare it to your code

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a1/#docs/lists/index.html

Comment: That is one of the main problems! The documentation sucks! jQuery Mobile team should really invest some time in documentation.

Comment: view source won't help much as it'll look much messy with dynamically added classes. They should provide some snippets.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna replace those jqm icons with your icons, read this:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html

See if the "custom icons" section would help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found this as an overview of the list: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YaZhS_8vaYo  It shows the arrows because the entire contents is wrapped in an `<a>`, I think if you put the link inside an H3, it will become more contained and not show the error.  The only thing I haven't figured out is a custom icon; you may be able to just float it.

Answer (score 0):

I viewed the page source and found it very helpful...
  [lists-split.html](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-split.html)

looks like this.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d">
    <li><a href="index.html">
        <img src="images/album-bb.jpg" />
        <h3>Broken Bells</h3>
        <p>Broken Bells</p>
    </a><a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Purchase album</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.html">

        <img src="images/album-hc.jpg" />
        <h3>Warning</h3>
        <p>Hot Chip</p>
    </a><a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Purchase album</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```